# Get image files from Facebook

Tags: perl

I am trying to pull images from a facebook posts.  The image urls contains some hex strings following the .jpg extension.

I have tried both LWP::Simple and WWW::Mechanize without success (error 501).  The same code works for the usual *.jpg address.

E.g. for LWP::Simple. This code works:

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $url = "http://sunsetvalleyorchids.com/images/orchid_images/Pot.%20William%20Farrell%20'Native%20Son'-150611.jpg";
my $file = "test.jpg";
getstore($url,$file);
```

This code does not work:

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $url = 
https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/v/t1.0-9/10670008_723959424306956_2403014210464990193_n.jpg?oh=bffe04b5a6e8c61381dbb85027e62a10&oe=5764ABCD

my $file = "test.jpg";
getstore($url,$file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $url = 
"https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/v/t1.0-9/10670008_723959424306956_2403014210464990193_n.jpg?oh=bffe04b5a6e8c61381dbb85027e62a10&oe=5764ABCD";
my $file = "test.jpg";
getstore($url,$file);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot the quotes.  The second code does't really work.  It does not save the output file "test.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

Using `LWP::Simple` makes it really hard to debug the underlying response.  Why not just go with `LWP::UserAgent`?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use Path::Tiny qw( path );

my $url
= 'https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/v/t1.0-9/10670008_723959424306956_2403014210464990193_n.jpg?oh=bffe04b5a6e8c61381dbb85027e62a10&oe=5764ABCD';
my $file = 'test.jpg';

my $ua       = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get( $url );
die 'Could not get file' if !$response->is_success || $response->header('X-Died');
path( $file )->spew( $response->content );
```